# Angular 2 With Web API File Upload

Tags: angular, file-upload, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to upload file using Angular 2 with web API but I am not getting file on the server.

My Controller method is

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]
    public IHttpActionResult Add(CourseDto course)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok("");
            //course.CompanyId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
            //var result = _courseService.Add(course);
            //return Ok(result.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

My CourseDto is

```
public class CourseDto

    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase CourseFile { get; set; }
    }
```

My Html file is

```
<form class="form-horizontal" #courseForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-4">Browse Course:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="file" name="file" (change)="onChange($event)"/>

                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!courseForm.form.valid">Add</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="close()">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </form>
```

Course Model For typescript is

```
export class Course {
    constructor(
        public courseFile?:any ,
        public id?: number
    ) {
    }
}
```

My Angular 2 Component method is  method is

```
onSubmit() {
        this.httpService.post("course/add", this.courseModel)
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.loggerService.notify(this, "Courses added successfully", Toast[Toast.success]);
                this.httpService.onUpdateModel();
                this.refreshModel();
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.courseModel.courseFile =event.target.files[0]; 

    }
```

Angular 2 Http Post Method is

```
post(url: string, data: any) {
        url = `${appConfig.apiUrl}${url}`;

        this.progressBarService.RequestStarted();


        return this.http.post(url, data)
            .finally(() => this.progressBarService.RequestFinished())
            .map((result: Response) => result.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

I successfully received the model in my Web API controller but without File. How to send the file to the web api controller model?

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();  
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;  
if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)  
{  
   foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)  
   {  
      var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];  
      var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + postedFile.FileName);
      postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
    }
}
```

thanks to [Angular 2 - File Upload using Web API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-2-file-upload-using-web-api/)

hope this help

Comment: God bless your soul, for saving me from this monstrosity I got myself into.

Comment: Anytime dude :)

Answer (score 2):

Step1: Ng2/4 Html-

```
 <input type="file" name="ProfilePhoto" id="ProfilePhoto" />
```

Step2: Ng2/4 Component-

```
import { ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
let files=this.elem.nativeElement.querySelector('#ProfilePhoto').files;
      let formData:FormData=new FormData();

      let file=files[0];
      formData.append('ProfilePhoto',file,file.name);         
      this.systemUserService.uploadSystemUserProfilePhoto(this.loginResponse.token,formData).subscribe(data => {  
      });
```

on service to be added below---
Note: here i used token based athentication, you can use normal http post.

```
uploadSystemUserProfilePhoto(token:string,formData: FormData): Observable<GlobalBaseResponse> {
            let options=this.getFileUploadHeader(token);                              
           return this.http.post(`${this.globalConstant.baseApiUrl}/account/uploadSystemUserProfilePhoto`, formData, options)
                   .map((response: Response) => {
                           this.globalBaseResponse = response.json();
                           return this.globalBaseResponse;
                   });
   }

           private getFileUploadHeader(token:string):RequestOptions{
            let headers = new Headers({ 
                    'Data-Type': 'json',
                    // 'Content-Type': false,
                    // 'Process-Data':false,
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+token 
            });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            return  options;
    }
```

Step3: on Asp.net web api project api controller method-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("uploadsystemuserprofilephoto")]       
    public IHttpActionResult UploadSystemUserProfilePhoto()
    {
        var response = new ResponseModel();

        var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath($"~/webshared/user/{postedFile.FileName}");
                postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }           

        response.IsSuccess = true;
        response.Message = "Success, User profile photo updated!";
        return Ok(response);            
    }
```

I think this will helpful for you.
Thanks